# How to make an autocompletion search form with data indexed in elasticsearch/kibana?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-dynamodb, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch

I have set a real time data indexation of my dynamodb streams into kibana. All work fine.

When i make a research in kibana search bar,  i can find data without any problem.

However i want to make a little search engine in an HTML webpage that i will create myself and be able to  to get the kibana index in real time directly from this webpage and making some features like autocompletion, auto suggest etc.

So i think that involve to use kibana as an API or something like that in order to get data by using javascript code.

But I have no idea about how to process for setting this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks